# Optimize the search in a long list of strings

Tags: python, search, list-comprehension

I have the following MWE, where I use a list comprehension to search through a list `ls` for strings that are contained `strings`:

```
import numpy as np

strings = ["ASD", "DSA", "ABC", "ABQ"]
ls     = np.asarray(["ASD", "DSA", "ASD", "ABC", "ABQ","ASD", "DSA", "ASD", "ABC", "ABQ","ASD", "DSA", "ASD", "ABC", "ABQ"])

for string in strings:
    print(len(ls[[string in s for s in ls]]))
```

This works as intended - however, the issue is that my `ls`-list is very long (10^9 entries), and the list comprehension takes a considerable time.

Is there a way to optimize the above code?

---

EDIT: I'm looking for a solution that allows me to record the individual occurences, i.e. 6, 3, 3 and 3

Comment: How long are each of the strings? If they are reasonably small you could use a **trie**.

Comment: Do you have to use `numpy`? Or can you accept proposals without it?

Comment: @Ralf I accept all proposals :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the ideas proposed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item); the best approach could be using `collections.Counter`.

This builds the `Counter` once, and then you can easily look up the individual elements you want the count for.

This could look like this:

```
import collections
import numpy as np
import timeit

def _get_data(as_numpy):
    data = []
    for _ in range(10**6):
        data.extend(["ASD", "DSA", "ASD", "ABC", "ABQ"])

    if as_numpy:
        data = np.asarray(data)

    return data

def f1(data):
    search_list = ["ASD", "DSA", "ABC", "ABQ"]
    result_list = []

    for search_str in search_list:
        result_list.append(
            len(data[[search_str in s for s in data]]))

    return result_list

def f2(data):
    search_list = ["ASD", "DSA", "ABC", "ABQ"]
    result_list = []

    c = collections.Counter(data)
    for search_str in search_list:
        result_list.append(
            c[search_str])

    return result_list

def f3(data):
    search_list = ["ASD", "DSA", "ABC", "ABQ"]
    result_list = []

    c = collections.Counter(data)
    for search_str in search_list:
        result_list.append(
            data.count(search_str))

    return result_list

def f4(data):
    # suggestion by user 'nixon' in another answer to this question
    search_list = ["ASD", "DSA", "ABC", "ABQ"]

    l, counts = np.unique(data, return_counts=True)
    # 'l' and 'counts' are in different order than 'search_list'
    result_list = [
        counts[np.where(l == search_str)[0][0]]
        for search_str in search_list]

    return result_list
```

To assure that these approaches get the same results:

```
data1 = _get_data(as_numpy=True)
data2 = _get_data(as_numpy=False)
assert f1(data1) == f2(data2) == f3(data2) == f4(data1)
```

And comparing the timings, I get:

```
print(timeit.timeit(
    'f(data)',
    'from __main__ import f1 as f, _get_data; data = _get_data(as_numpy=True)',
    number=10))
print(timeit.timeit(
    'f(data)',
    'from __main__ import f2 as f, _get_data; data = _get_data(as_numpy=False)',
    number=10))
print(timeit.timeit(
    'f(data)',
    'from __main__ import f3 as f, _get_data; data = _get_data(as_numpy=False)',
    number=10))
print(timeit.timeit(
    'f(data)',
    'from __main__ import f4 as f, _get_data; data = _get_data(as_numpy=True)',
    number=10))

# f1 48.2 sec
# f2  1.7 sec
# f3  3.8 sec
# f4  9.7 sec
```

As you can see, there is an order of magnitud in time difference.

Does that work for your case?

---

EDIT: added approach using `numpy.unique`, similar to the one suggested by @nixon in another answer to this question; it still seems to be slower than using `collections.Counter`.

Comment: @N08 my tests seem to indicate that `numpy` is slower than `Counter` for this task.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with `return_counts=True` and use [`np.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) to perform boolean indexation and keep only the values in `ls` that are present in `strings` on both the unique values and the counts:

```
l, counts = np.unique(ls, return_counts=True)
mask = np.in1d(l,strings)

l[mask]
#array(['ABC', 'ABQ', 'ASD', 'DSA'], dtype='<U3')

counts[mask]
array([3, 3, 6, 3], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Thanks - however, this gives me the total sum. I'd like to get the sum for each individual string in `strings`

Comment: I see, that's why it always helps to add a sample output

Comment: Edited, should do what you want now

Comment: Just a headsup: if @N08 needs the result to be in the same order as the original `strings` list, then additional processing seems to be requiered, because `l` and `counts` will not necesarely be in the same order as `strings`.